# Get current zswap memory usage and statistics

Tags: linux, zswap

The [zswap documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/zswap.txt) says:

> ```
> Zswap seeks to be simple in its policies.  Sysfs attributes allow for one user
> controlled policy:
> * max_pool_percent - The maximum percentage of memory that the compressed
>     pool can occupy.
> ```

This specifies the *maximum* percentage of memory the compressed pool can occupy.

How do I find out:

- The *current* percentage of memory occupied by the compressed pool
- How much of this pool is in use
- Compression ratios, hit rates, and other useful info

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Current statistics:

```
# grep -R . /sys/kernel/debug/zswap/
```

Compression ratio:

```
# cd /sys/kernel/debug/zswap
# perl -E  "say $(cat stored_pages) * 4096 / $(cat pool_total_size)"
```

Current settings:

```
$ grep -R . /sys/module/zswap
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Do you have a source for your `4096` magic number? Welcome to Unix.SE!

Comment: 4096 is the size of the normal memory pages. Modern CPUs are supporting pages larger than 4k, called huge pages, but those are not swap-able.

Comment: 4096 is the page size of an **x86** and **x86-64** (AMD64). (ignoring the larger page sizes)

Answer (score 2):

Create **/usr/local/bin/zswap** with content:

```
#!/bin/bash

MDL=/sys/module/zswap
DBG=/sys/kernel/debug/zswap
PAGE=$[`cat $DBG/stored_pages`*4096]
POOL=$[`cat $DBG/pool_total_size`]

Show(){
    printf "========\n$1\n========\n"
    grep -R . $2 2>&1 | sed 's|.*/||'
}

Show Settings $MDL
Show Stats    $DBG

printf "\nCompression ratio: "

[ $POOL -gt 0 ] && {
     echo "scale=3;$PAGE/$POOL" | bc
} || echo zswap disabled
```

Make the file executable (*# chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/zswap*) and launch it. Example:

```
# zswap
========
Settings
========
uevent: Permission denied
same_filled_pages_enabled:Y
enabled:Y
max_pool_percent:20
compressor:zstd
zpool:zbud
accept_threshold_percent:90
========
Stats
========
same_filled_pages:72227
stored_pages:394760
pool_total_size:660660224
duplicate_entry:0
written_back_pages:0
reject_compress_poor:345
reject_kmemcache_fail:0
reject_alloc_fail:0
reject_reclaim_fail:0
pool_limit_hit:0

Compression ratio: 2.447
```